# clicking on button in iframe with python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to access website with python selenium. I am going to place that I cant click on the button. any help please?
please find my code on the below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

path_to_chromedriver = "chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path_to_chromedriver)

url = 'https://www.mail.com/'
driver.get(url)
```

how to click on button `"Agree and Continue"` using `css selector` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element  `Agree and Continue` is present inside `nested` `iframe` you need to switch both the iframe first and then click on the element.

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`()
Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`()

```
driver.get("https://www.mail.com/")
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe.permission-core-iframe")))
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src^='https://plus.mail']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']"))).click()
```

you need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

---

Jump out from iframe you need to use.

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```